# How to configure FindBugs to run only on one project in a multi-module maven project

Tags: maven, findbugs

I use the findbugs-maven-plugin to check for bugs with maven. My maven project is a multi-module project that roughly looks as follows:

```
java-module
    pom.xml
    src/ ...
pom.xml
scala-module
    pom.xml
    src/ ...
```

I use Jenkins to build and test the project, and Jenkins runs goal `findbugs:findbugs` in the top-most directory. Since FindBugs reports many spurious warnings for code that is generated by the Scala compiler, I would like to tell FindBugs not to analyze the code in `scala-module`. However, when I run `findbugs:findbugs` in the top-most directory, it always analyzes all classes in `java-module` and `scala-module`. How can I tell maven to ignore `scala-module` as a whole? I know about FindBugs exclude filters but I would to have a configuration option for FindBugs that tells it to simply not analyze the code in a certain submodule.

FindBugs is configured in `pom.xml` in subdirectory `java-module` as follows:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${version.plugin.codehaus.findbugs}</version>
      <configuration>
        <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
        <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Despite the configuration being done only for the `java-module`, FindBugs will always also analyze `scala-module`.

Comment: Where is your findbugs configured? In the parent pom? Can you provide the configuration stanza?

Comment: @noahlz I have edited my post and added the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a configuration the scala-module `pom.xml` that explicitly instructs findbugs to skip the module, i.e.

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Note that Maven often requires you to repeat boilerplate XML for cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

Noahlz's answer did not work for me, but adding the following snippet to the sub-module's POM.xml did the trick.

```
<properties>
    <findbugs.skip>true</findbugs.skip>
</properties>
```